# Java Web Service client authentication using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I've used default eclipse wizard to create a web service client (File>New>Other and select a wizard for web service client). The classes were generated and I was able to use service methods with code like this:

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
import com.olsn.ws.ShipmentService_PortType;
import com.olsn.ws.ShipmentService_ServiceLocator;

public class wsClient {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ServiceException, RemoteException {

             //To load the web service and to create the client
             ShipmentService_ServiceLocator WS = new ShipmentService_ServiceLocator();              
             ShipmentService_PortType client = WS.getShipmentServicePort();

             //To get Close status for Issue
             System.out.println(client.getCloseDesc("35557"));

             //To get the list of NetP projects
             for (int i=1; i<client.getProjects().length;i++)
                 {System.out.println(client.getProjects()[i].toString());}

           }

     }
```

The problem now is that the username and password were introduced, and I don't know how to modify my code to access the server, I was trying to add authenticator:

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

Authenticator myAuth = new Authenticator() 
{
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "password".toCharArray());
    }
};

Authenticator.setDefault(myAuth);
```

or change _initShipmentServiceProxy() method of generated proxy class

```
  private void _initShipmentServiceProxy() {
    try {
      shipmentService_PortType = (new com.olsn.ws.ShipmentService_ServiceLocator()).getShipmentServicePort();
      if (shipmentService_PortType != null) {
        if (_endpoint != null)
        {
          ((javax.xml.rpc.Stub)shipmentService_PortType)._setProperty("javax.xml.rpc.service.endpoint.address", _endpoint);
          **((javax.xml.rpc.Stub)shipmentService_PortType)._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "user");
          ((javax.xml.rpc.Stub)shipmentService_PortType)._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");**
        }  
        else
          _endpoint = (String)((javax.xml.rpc.Stub)shipmentService_PortType)._getProperty("javax.xml.rpc.service.endpoint.address");
      }

    }
    catch (javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException serviceException) {}
  }
```

But I continue getting these errors:

```
org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client.Authentication
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: Access denied to operation getCloseDesc
```

Please advise what should I change?

Comment: how to authenticate in server...Please share the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error I assume you are using `Axis` so the `Authenticator` won't work on it. If you want to perform the client's basic authentication to `Axis` service, you need to do something like this:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClass.class);

private ShipmentService_PortType proxy;

public void init()
        throws Exception {
    ShipmentService_ServiceLocator locator = new ShipmentService_ServiceLocator();
    try {
        LOGGER.debug("Initializing shipment service...");
        proxy = locator.getShipmentServicePort(new URL("yourServiceEndpointURL"));
        ((ShipmentServicePortBindingStub) proxy).setUsername("yourUsername");
        ((ShipmentServicePortBindingStub) proxy).setPassword("yourPassword");
        ((ShipmentServicePortBindingStub) proxy).setTimeout(10000);
        LOGGER.debug("Shipment service successfully initialized.");
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error in shipment client initialization", e);
        throw new Exception("Error in shipment client initialization.");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error in shipment client initialization", e);
        throw new Exception("Error in shipment client initialization.");
    }
}
```

And only when this `init()` method will be called you will be able to call your client's methods through this:

```
proxy.getCloseDesc("35557");
```