# How do I use the web service classes generated with Eclipse from WSDL file?

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, axis, webservices-client

I used eclipse Oxygen to create a Web Service Client for consuming an axis 1.4 web service.
It generated 3 packages:
1 - datamodel.
2 - Message and Response Structure.
3- Service. 
1 & 2 are fine I have no issues with these.

Inside service package there are 5 classes:
1- ServiceName.
2- ServiceNameProxy.
3- ServiceNameService.
4- ServiceNameServiceLocator.
5- ServiceNameSoapBindingStub.

I need to understand what these are ? AND
How to call the web service methods with parameters?

Finally & most important, if I use the proxy class to call methods, such as submit(), provided by the ServiceNameProxy class, how do I perform authentication functions such as setUsername and setPassword, which is only provided in the ServiceNameSoapBindingStub method?

IFF I don'd use the proxy class and use the stub class instead, to call the submit() method provided, I can't set the endpoint which I guess the proxy class is automatically doing for me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question was halfway answered in this other post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145326/how-to-use-the-webservice-client-classes-generated-with-eclipse#_=_]() Any help with regards to how to handle autheentication would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513841/java-web-service-client-authentication-using-eclipse